# Simulating a controller device in Windows

Tags: windows, kernel, usb, device

I am trying to make a Windows kernel driver that can spoof devices. For instance, how could I make a driver that simulates a usb plugin event and then is shown in the device manager? I have been searching for days trying to find anything relating to this, but I have not been able to find any source code for controller drivers. I don't really care the type of controller I just want it to me recognized as a controller by Windows. I have found many Linux drivers but none for Windows.

I really just need to be pointed in the right direction because right now I have no idea how to start since I have found 0 documentation on controllers by Micrsoft or any 3rd party. If anyone could provide driver code or any sort of documentation relating to controllers on Windows, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: https://github.com/ViGEm/ViGEmBus

Comment: @Luke I already looked at that before posting this question but that is for simulating a controller for some sort of process or something. I ran that program and no controller device ever got registered. If you look at their GitHub you can see another program that it supposed to work with.

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/ViGEm/ViGEmClient#api-usage) seems relatively straightforward. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Luke That is a developer api but I can't even get the device to show up when I run it so there is not point trying to use the developer api.

Comment: When you run what? I just wrote a little program using the API to connect a virtual Xbox 360 controller and it shows up in device manager.

Comment: @Luke Running the ViGem Driver does nothing what do u mean? I ran the executable from their releases page (talking about ViGEmBus not the client) and then queried the driver to ensure it was running but no controller device is found in my device manager.

Comment: @Luke Going to control panel then devices does not show up a controller device like it does for plugging in an actual controller or any other usb device. However, going to Device Manager then "System devices" does show the driver but nowhere is it specified as a controller which is kind of the whole point.

Comment: @IgnoreException The release binary only installs the driver. It doesn't actually create any emulated devices until a client directs it to do so via the [client API](https://github.com/ViGEm/ViGEmClient).

Comment: @Luke Alright ill check it out and try to figure out how to get that api to work then get back to u thanks for that info.